# Is Retrofit+Okhttp using httpCaching as a default in Android?

Tags: android, http, http-caching, retrofit, okhttp

I use [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) and [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) in one of our applications.

I can't really find a good explanation for the default behaviour of Retrofit.

If Okhttp is on the class path it will be automatically used. But as far as I can see it the default HttpResponseCache is null.

Do I need to explicitly enable caching with Retrofit and Okhttp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should manually create your OkHttpClient and configure it how you like. In this case you should install a cache. Once you have that create an [OkClient](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/client/OkClient.html) and pass it to Retrofit's [RestAdapter.Builder](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RestAdapter.html)

Also, no caching for HTTP POST requests. GETs will be cached, however.

Comment: I added the code I used in separate answer because I think this would be interesting for other people as well. Since I copied it from your example I hope the code is ok.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445177/trying-to-make-use-of-httpcache-android says that there is no need to configure the cache anymore. Is this correct?

Answer (score 15):

Correct implementation for OkHttpClient v2:

```
int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "HttpCache");
Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDir, cacheSize);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cache(cache)
    .build();
```

see [documentation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#response-caching)

Comment: setCache does not exist in 3. so you can use `new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(cache).build();`

Comment: Thanks @frostymarvelous

Answer (score 8):

**DEPRECATED for OkHttpClient v2.0.0 and higher**

As Jesse Wilson pointed out you need to create your own cache.
The following code should create a 10MB cache.

```
File httpCacheDirectory = new File(application.getApplicationContext()
    .getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), "HttpCache");

HttpResponseCache httpResponseCache = null;
try {
   httpResponseCache = new HttpResponseCache(httpCacheDirectory, 10 * 1024);
} catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create http cache", e);
}

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setResponseCache(httpResponseCache);
builder.setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient));
```

The code is based on [Jesse Wilsons example on Github](https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/5889518).

Comment: if this is set on a post would it be ignored? because I am setting it on my general builder which is used for every request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445177/trying-to-make-use-of-httpcache-android I am actually getting this error... and if I do not use httpResponseCache.install it errors that new HttpResponseCache cannot be used outside... it is not public..

Comment: isn't that a 10MB cache?

Comment: Yes looks more like a 10MB Cache ;)

Comment: I saw the docs and found that `HttpResponseCache` was added in API Level 13, so does `okHttp` caches below API Level 13? If yes, how?

Comment: @NelsonOsacky @Janusz Actually no, it's 10KB, not 10MB. Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html
`long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB`

The same rule applies to OkHttp's `Cache` constructor.

Comment: fyi this is a deprecated answer http://square.github.io/okhttp/1.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#setResponseCache(java.net.ResponseCache)