# OkHttp + Retrofit offline cache not working

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

I'm requesting json data from two servers. OkHttp doesn't cache responses from the first server, responses from the second server are caching properly.

Response from the first server, cache is not working for some reason:

```
<--- HTTP 200
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2230
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sat, 28 Mar 2015 11:34:13 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 28 Mar 2015 10:34:13 GMT
Vary: *
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2015 10:57:01 GMT
Content-Length: 1381
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1427540192625
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1427540192940
<--- END HTTP (1381-byte body)
```

Response from the first server when device is offline:

```
---> HTTP GET
Cache-Control: public, only-if-cached, max-stale=2419200
---> END HTTP (no body)
<--- HTTP 504
<--- END HTTP (0-byte body)
```

Response from the second server, cache works:

```
<--- HTTP 200
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2015 11:19:51 GMT
Server: nginx/1.6.2
X-Berry-Env: p4
X-Berry-Version: 2.10.0.96e8b7c
X-Powered-By: Express
Connection: keep-alive
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1427541591103
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1427541591385
<--- END HTTP (92663-byte body)
```

Response from the second server when device is offline:

```
<--- HTTP 200
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2015 11:19:51 GMT
Server: nginx/1.6.2
X-Berry-Env: p4
X-Berry-Version: 2.10.0.96e8b7c
X-Powered-By: Express
Connection: keep-alive
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1427541591103
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1427541591385
Warning: 110 HttpURLConnection "Response is stale"
Validating map...
<--- END HTTP (92663-byte body)
```

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429046/can-retrofit-with-okhttp-use-cache-data-when-offline), here's my rest adapter:

```
protected RestAdapter getRestAdapter(final Context context) {
    if (restAdapter == null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .create();

        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
        Cache cache = new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setCache(cache);

        restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(client))
                .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                        if (Utils.isOnline(context)) {
                            int maxAge = 60;
                            request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge);
                        } else {
                            int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28;
                            request.addHeader("Cache-Control",
                                    "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();
        restAdapter.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
    }

    return restAdapter;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using network interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Ivan's answer, OkHttp3 Caching will not work with post requests.
To cache post requests you have to use some other mechanism.