# How to Cache the response in squareup.okhttp3

Tags: java, android, caching, okhttp

I am trying to cache the http response through OKhttp
but unable to find some good example or documentation.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What you wanna do? Isn't enough SharedPreferences? Ok. What about saving it in a DB?

Comment: I am using the library of OK http . I want to cache the http response using its cache option. So i wants to know what are the available options to do this.

Comment: Did you [check this](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/)?

Answer (score 9):

this will cache all your response for 2 minutes

```
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient () {
    Cache cache = new Cache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "http-cache"), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(provideCacheInterceptor())
            .cache(cache)
            .build();
}

Interceptor provideCacheInterceptor () {
    return new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept (Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed( chain.request() );
            CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                    .maxAge( 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES )
                    .build();

            return response.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl.toString() )
                    .build();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: If we don't set the **cacheControl**, how long does OkHttp keep the cache around for all of its requests?

Comment: how to use it? Where is some example? It is just part of parts code. I think it is bad  answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
public final class FeedInterceptor {

private final static String TAG = FeedInterceptor.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * Validate cache, return stream. Return cache if no network.
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static Interceptor getOnlineInterceptor(final Context context){
    Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

            String headers = response.header("Cache-Control");
            if(NetworkUtils.isConnected(context) && (headers == null
                  || headers.contains("no-store")
                  || headers.contains("must-revalidate")
                  || headers.contains("no-cache")
                  || headers.contains("max-age=0"))) {

                LOGD(TAG, "Returning fresh response");
                return response.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=600")
                        .build();
            } else{
                LOGD(TAG, "Returning old response");
                return response;
            }
        }
    };

    return interceptor;
}

/**
 * Get me cache.
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static Interceptor getOfflineInterceptor(final Context context){
    Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            if(!NetworkUtils.isConnected(context)){
                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached")
                        .build();
            }

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    };

    return interceptor;
}

} // End FeedInterceptor
```

**And the client:**

```
private OkHttpClient createCacheClient(Context context){

    File httpCacheDirecotory = new File(context.getCacheDir(), FILE);
    Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirecotory, CACHE_SIZE);

    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(FeedInterceptor.getOnlineInterceptor(context))
            .addInterceptor(FeedInterceptor.getOfflineInterceptor(context))
            .cache(cache)
            .build();
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429046/can-retrofit-with-okhttp-use-cache-data-when-offline)

Answer (score 2):

There is a sample here [CacheResponse.java](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/3f7a3344a4c85aa3bbb879dabac5ee625ab987f3/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CacheResponse.java)

```
Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDirectory, cacheSize);

client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cache(cache)
    .build();
```

The [javadoc for Cache](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Cache.html) has examples for forcing fresh or cached responses.

Comment: Yuri it is working, but i want to do runtime memory cache instead of disk memory and also wants to know how can i remove cache further.
I am using the common http Client here.

Comment: The design of Cache is based around a real filesystem AFAIK. It doesn't look possible by public API. I suspect you need to either use Cache with a FileSystem or implement your own caching strategy in interceptors