# OkHttpClient cannot resolve method setCache

Tags: retrofit, okhttp

I'm trying to set a cache for Retrofit so that it does not have to retrieve the data constantly. I followed [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429046/can-retrofit-with-okhttp-use-cache-data-when-offline) as it appears to be in the right direction of what I need.

I have the following (which is identical from the SO)

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.networkInterceptors().add(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR);
File httpCacheDirectory = new File(getCacheDir(), "responses");
int cacheSize = 10*1024*1024;
Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize);
client.setCache(cache);
```

However, `client.setCache(cache)` returns an error `cannot resolve method setCache`.

What am I doing wrong here? I have retrofit 2.1.0 and okhttp3 3.4.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In 3.x a bunch of methods on `OkHttpClient` were moved into methods on `OkHttpClient.Builder`. You want something like this:

```
File httpCacheDirectory = new File(getCacheDir(), "responses");
int cacheSize = 10*1024*1024;
Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR)
    .cache(cache)
    .build();
```

Comment: I am getting an error Cannot resolve symbol `REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR`

Comment: Stop copy-pasting boss 

Answer (score 0):

```
File httpCacheDirectory = new File(getCacheDir(), "responses");
int cacheSize = 10*1024*1024;
Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR)
    .cache(cache)
    .build();

/////////and

public static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            if (Global.networkConnection()) {
                int maxAge = 60; // read from cache for 1 minute
                return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge)
                        .build();
            } else {
                int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // tolerate 4-weeks stale
                return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                        .build();
            }
        }
    };
```