# how to make network calls efficiently in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, retrofit

I have to make network calls in every page which is a fragment in viewpager.

**The Problem** is that the viewpager calls onCreateView() of adjacent fragments having  network requests (I am using retrofit) which makes the progress dialog of retrofit request still visible after making the network request.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

Android allows a min value of 1 in setOffScreenPageLimit.

I also used

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisible()){
        if(isVisibleToUser){
            Log.d("MyTag","TopFramgnet:My Fragment is visible");
        }else{
            Log.d("MyTag","TopFramgnet:My Fragment is not visible");
        }
    }
}
```

But this method is not called every time when i switch to the fragment.
So, How to make the network calls efficiently?

**Second Problem** is that how can i reload the fragment so that if i changed something, it can reload its view by making network request again?

Please guide me, I can't find anything that solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need enable cache in retrofit. For example

```
RestAdapter.Builder builder= new RestAdapter.Builder()
   .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;versions=1");
            if (MyApplicationUtils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                int maxAge = 60; // read from cache for 1 minute
                request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge);
            } else {
                int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // tolerate 4-weeks stale
                request.addHeader("Cache-Control", 
                    "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale);
            }
        }
});
```

[Can Retrofit with OKHttp use cache data when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429046/can-retrofit-with-okhttp-use-cache-data-when-offline)

After that you get data from cache if data is fairly new.