# Bypass cache and then update it in retrofit

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp, cache-control

What i want to do is at a specific time bypass cache, make an http request and then update the new result back to cache for the next time I need it. Is there any way to do this with retrofit + okhttp in android??

Comment: You need to be more specific. What cache are you trying to bypass? What have you tried so far, and what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I have created a http client like described in the following stackoverflow link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429046/can-retrofit-with-okhttp-use-cache-data-when-offline . I use cached data for offline usage and for navigating inside my android app when inside max-age. What i want is give user the ability to force update the data of the app at a specific time. In that case, do make a http request to the server, get data and then update cache data for future usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a network request by using [`CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CacheControl.html#FORCE_NETWORK) for the request. You could either do it when creating the request, or in an interceptor.

Another way would be to use [`Cache.evictAll()`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Cache.java#L313) to clear the cache completely. Any subsequent requests will be put in the cache.

You can use a [`Timer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to schedule and trigger the eviction process.

Comment: Cache.remove(request) is not a public method. How could i use it?

Comment: Will CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK update my cached file, so the next time i use cache get the updated data;

Comment: Yes, it should update the response data for that request.