# Offline mode with Retrofit 2 Cache-Control

Tags: android, retrofit2, cache-control, offline-caching

I am working on a android app which has requirement of offline mode , I am using retrofit 2 with cache control , but facing problem that cache files are not getting created and only file is created in that folder is named journal.I am posting my ApiClient.java file code here.

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.something.com/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private static APIInterfaces apiInterface;
private  static Context mcontext=getApplicationContext();


static Interceptor OFFLINE_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        if (!isConnected()) {
            int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // tolerate 4-weeks stale
            request = request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                    .build();
        }

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
};


static Interceptor ONLINE_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        int maxAge = 60; // read from cache
        return response.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge)
                .build();
    }
};



protected static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {

        createFolder();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();


        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .cache(new Cache(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "something"), 10 * 1024 * 1024)) // 10 MB
                .addInterceptor(OFFLINE_INTERCEPTOR)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(ONLINE_INTERCEPTOR)
                .build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL).client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}


public static APIInterfaces getApiInterface() {
    if (apiInterface == null)
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(APIInterfaces.class);
    return apiInterface;
}



private static boolean isConnected() {
    try {
        android.net.ConnectivityManager e = (android.net.ConnectivityManager) mcontext.getSystemService(
                Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = e.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, e.toString());
    }

    return false;
}

public  static boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (mcontext.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mcontext,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        return true;
    }
}



private static void createFolder() {
    if (isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Something");

        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone please explain what is problem with above code.

Comment: Checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429046/can-retrofit-with-okhttp-use-cache-data-when-offline

Comment: Did you tried to load data offline? Is it success or failure?

Comment: @sreehari caching files are not getting created in that case how to load data offline .... no data without files

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru thanks for the answer but i want know what is the problem specific to my code ....

Comment: Have you tried `networkInterceptors()` instead of `interceptors()` Have a look here, https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use interceptors to change headers it does not make any adjustments before `CacheStrategy.isCacheable()` is called.

Try changing `interceptors()` with `networkInterceptors()` call.

Have a look here:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

Also, you can't cache POST requests with OkHttp’s cache. You’ll need to store them using some other mechanism, [see this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Cache.java#L230%5D)

**Other mechanisms:**

There are several methods, one can be storing the online results to a local database and retrieve it from there if offline which most people do, the second option is to override `OKHTTP` but that will be costly for a mobile device in terms of performance over benefit, the third one is obviously converting your POST API structure to GET

But, have a look [here](https://github.com/ArthurSav/AutoCaching) it contains a blog article too, which will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much  you saved my day ......problem was with "can't cache POST requests with OkHttp’s cache"

Comment: @PoonamParth  Welcome :)

Comment: Now i am stuck with problem which mechanism to use for post request caching ...read some stack over flow which suggested to convert post request to get  one but i think there can be a much better answer then this .....can you suggest something ???

Comment: @PoonamParth go with local database cache