# How to influence OkHttp cache usage?

Tags: okhttp, http-caching

You can add a cache to an `OkHttpClient` which will work according to the various cache-related HTTP header like `cache-control`:

```kotlin
val okHttpClient =
    OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
        cache(Cache(File("http_cache"), 50 * 1024 * 1024))
    }.build()
```

There is a resource for which the server (which is not controlled by me) specifies `cache-control: no-cache` in the response. But I want to cache it anyway, because I know that under certain circumstances it is safe to do so.

I thought I could intercept the response and set headers accordingly:

```kotlin
val okHttpClient =
    OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
        cache(Cache(File("http_cache"), 50 * 1024 * 1024))
        addInterceptor { chain ->
            val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
            response
                .newBuilder()
                .header("cache-control", "max-age=1000") // Enable caching
                .removeHeader("pragma")  // Remove any headers that might conflict with caching
                .removeHeader("expires") // ...
                .removeHeader("x-cache") // ...
                .build()
        }
    }.build()
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Apparently, the caching decisions are made before the interceptor intercepts. Using `addNetworkInterceptor()` instead of `addInterceptor()` does not work either.

The opposite - disabling caching when the server allows it by setting `cache-control: no-cache` - also does not work.

**Edit:**

[Yuri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70052313/443836) is correct. `addNetworkInterceptor()` with `.header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=1000")` works, and `.header("cache-control", "max-age=1000")` also works.

But when running my experiments, I had made some false assumptions. This is what I found out later:

- The OkHttp cache does not cache responses for POST requests at all. [(Source)](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1969)
- "Note that `no-cache` does not mean "don't cache". `no-cache` allows caches to store a response, but requires them to revalidate it before reuse. If the sense of "don't cache" that you want is actually "don't store", then `no-store` is the directive to use." [(Source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be a networkInterceptor, but it definitely works.

Try `.header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=1000")`, which should cache for  15 minutes.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23503804/1542667

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question accordingly.